# While loop with switch statement in it not exiting

Tags: c

I have a problem with my c code. At the beginning of the code when you run it, it stays in the loop even though it exits the switch and the condition is met. How do you solve this problem? Here is the code. `

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int total(int x,int y,int z);
int male(int a,int b);
int female(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e);
void calories();

/*declaration of file pointers*/
FILE *fptr1;
FILE *fptr2;
FILE *fptr3;

char gender;

/*struct login data type*/
struct login {
    char username[10];
    char password[50];
};

/*struct clients data type*/
struct clients{
    char clientf_name[15];
    char clientl_name[20];
    };

/*struct calorie data type*/
struct calorie{
    int carbs;
    int protein;
    int fat;
};

/*struct bodyfat data type*/
struct bodyfat{
    int bodyweight;
    int waist;
    int wrist;
    int hip;
    int forearm;
};


int main()
{
    /*declaration of variables and constants*/
    struct login user;
    struct clients client;
    struct bodyfat percent;
    char login_user[10];
    char login_password[50];
    char str[100];
    char string[100];
    char client1[50];
    char stringline[150];
    char option;
    char choice;
    int condition = 1;
    int compare1 = 1;
    int compare2 = 1;
    int change;
    int bodyfat_percent;
/*opens files and assign them to a file pointer*/
    fptr1 = fopen("Usernames.txt","a+");
    fptr2 = fopen("Passwords.txt","a+");

    printf("Welcome!\n\n");//prints welcome message

    while((choice != 'Y') || (choice != 'y') || (choice !='N') || (choice != 'n')){
        system("cls");

        printf("Would you like to create an account? (Y-Yes/N-No)\n");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);

    /*switch case of persons choice*/
        switch(choice){
        /*if choice is 'Y' user enters name and password for their account*/
                case 'y':
                case 'Y':system("cls");
                        printf("Please enter the name you would like\n");
                        scanf("%s", user.username);
                        printf("Please enter the password you would like\n");
                        scanf("%s",user.password);
                        fprintf(fptr1,"%s",user.username);
                        fprintf(fptr1,"\n");
                        fprintf(fptr2,"%s",user.password);
                        fprintf(fptr2,"\n");
                        printf("Press Enter to continue...\n");
                        getch();
                        break;
        /*if choice is 'N' user decides whether to exit or continue to login*/
                case 'n':
                case 'N':while ((choice != 'Y') || (choice != 'y') || (choice != 'N') || (choice != 'n'))
                            {
                            system("cls");
                            printf("Would you like to exit (Y-Yes/N-No)?\n");
                            scanf(" %c",&choice);
                            switch(choice){
                                case'y':
                                case'Y':system("cls");
                                        printf("Program is exiting Good bye!\n");
                                        exit(0);
                                case'n':
                                case'N':printf("Press Enter to continue to login....\n");
                                        getch();
                                        break;
                                default:printf("Incorrect entry. Press Enter to try again\n");
                                        getch();
                                        break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                default: printf("Incorrect entry. Press Enter to try again/n");
                        getch();
                        break;
            }
    }
    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);


/*check if files were open or not*/
    if((fptr1 = fopen("Usernames.txt","r"))== NULL){
            printf("File was not opened\n");
        }
    if((fptr2 = fopen("Passwords.txt","r"))== NULL){
            printf("File was not opened\n");
        }
    /*do-while loop to log in to account*/
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter username:");
        scanf("%s",login_user);
        printf("Enter password:");
        scanf("%s",login_password);
   /*while loop to read strings from file and compare*/
        while(compare1 != 0){
            fscanf(fptr1,"%s",str);
            compare1 = strcmp(str,login_user);
        }
        while(compare2 != 0){
            fscanf(fptr2,"%s",string);
            compare2 = strcmp(string,login_password);
        }
    /*if statement that checks if compare 1 and compare 2 is equal to 0*/
        if((compare1 == 0)&&(compare2 == 0)){
            printf("\nWelcome %s\n",login_user);
        }else{
            printf("incorrect username or password please try again");
        }
    }while((compare1 != 0) && (compare2 != 0));
    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);

    /*while loop*/
    while(1){//1 is used in the while loop to make it an infinite loop
        system("cls");
        printf("Choose an option below\n");
        printf("A.Add client\n");
        printf("B.Calculate calories\n");
        printf("C.Body fat calculator\n");
        printf("D.Exit\n");
        scanf(" %c",&option);

        /*switch function*/
        switch(option)
        {
            /*if option is A user inputs client's information*/
            case 'A':system("cls");
                     fptr3 = fopen("Clients.txt","a");
                     printf("Please enter clients first name\n");
                     scanf("%s",client.clientf_name);
                     printf("Please enter clients last name\n");
                     scanf("%s",client.clientl_name);
                     /*while loop to get users body weight, waist size,
                     wrist size, hip size and forearm size based on gender*/
                     while(condition == 1){
                        printf("Please enter clients gender (M/F)\n");
                        scanf(" %c",&gender);
                        if(((gender == 'M')||(gender == 'm'))){
                           printf("Please enter bodyweight(lbs)\n");
                           scanf("%d",&percent.bodyweight);
                           printf("Please enter waist size\n");
                           scanf("%d",&percent.waist);
                           printf("Press Enter too continue....\n");
                           getch();
                           condition = 0;//condition changed to 0 to end loop;
                        }else if((gender == 'F')||(gender == 'f')){
                            printf("Please enter bodyweight(lbs)\n");
                            scanf("%d",&percent.bodyweight);
                            printf("Please enter waist size\n");
                            scanf("%d",&percent.waist);
                            printf("Please enter wrist size\n");
                            scanf("%d",&percent.wrist);
                            printf("Please enter hip size\n");
                            scanf("%d",percent.hip);
                            printf("Please enter forearm size\n");
                            scanf("%d",percent.forearm);
                            printf("Press Enter to continue...\n");
                            getch();
                            condition = 0;//condition changed to 0
                        }
                     }
                     /*store values to file*/
                     fprintf(fptr3,"%s %s\n",client.clientf_name,client.clientl_name);
                     fprintf(fptr3,"%c \n",gender);
                     fprintf(fptr3,"bodyweight:%d lbs\n",percent.bodyweight);
                     fprintf(fptr3,"waist:%d inches\n",percent.waist);
                     fprintf(fptr3,"wrist:%d inches\n",percent.wrist);
                     fprintf(fptr3,"hip:%d inches\n",percent.hip);
                     fprintf(fptr3,"forearm:%d inches\n",percent.forearm);
                     fclose(fptr3);
                     break;
            /*if case B calories function calculates calories*/
            case 'B':system("cls");
                     calories();
                     break;
            /*if case C based on gender the body fat percentage is calculated*/
            case 'C':if((gender == 'M') || (gender == 'm')){//gender is male calculate body fat percentage using body weight and waist size
                        fptr3 = fopen("Clients.txt","a");
                        system("cls");
                        printf("Enter body weight (Lbs):");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.bodyweight);
                        printf("Enter waist measurement:");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.waist);
                        bodyfat_percent = male(percent.bodyweight,percent.waist);//male function to calculate body fat percentage for males
                        printf("your body fat percentage is: %d",bodyfat_percent);
                        fprintf(fptr3,"body fat percentage is: %d\n",bodyfat_percent);
                        printf("Press Enter to go back to menu...");
                        getch();
                        fclose(fptr3);
                     }else if((gender == 'F') || (gender == 'f')){//gender is female calculate the body fat percentage with
                         //body weight, waist size, wrist size, hip size and forearm size
                        fptr3 = fopen("Clients.txt","a");
                        system("cls");
                        printf("Enter body weight:");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.bodyweight);

                        printf("Enter wrist measurement:");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.wrist);

                        printf("Enter waist measurement:");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.waist);

                        printf("Enter hip measurement:");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.hip);

                        printf("Enter forearm measurement:");
                        scanf(" %d",&percent.forearm);

                        bodyfat_percent = female(percent.bodyweight,percent.wrist,percent.waist,percent.hip,percent.forearm);//female function to calculate BFP for females
                        fprintf(fptr3,"body fat percentage is: %d\n",bodyfat_percent);
                        printf("Body fat percent is: %.1f\%\n",bodyfat_percent);
                        }
                        fclose(fptr3);
                        break;
            /*if case is D exit program*/
            case 'D':printf("Program is exiting. Good Bye!");
                     exit(0);
                     break;
        }
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;//returns 0 if code runs successful
}

/*total function that calculates the total calorie intake for the day*/
int total(int x,int y,int z){
    x = x*4;
    y = y*4;
    z = z*9;
    int c = x + y + z;
    return c;
}

/*male function that calculates body fat percentage for male clients*/
int male(int a,int b){
    int c = (a * 1.082) + 94.42;
    int d = b * 4.15;
    int e = c - d;
    int f = a - e;
    int g = (f * 100)/a;
    return g;
}

/*female function that calculates body fat percentage for female clients*/
int female(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e){
    int f = (a * 0.732) + 8.987;
    int g = b / 3.140;
    int h = c * 0.157;
    int i = d * 0.249;
    int j = e * 0.434;
    int k = f + g - h - i + j;
    int l = a - k;
    int m = (l * 100)/a;
    return m;
}

/*calories function that calculates the total number of
calories for each day of the week and displays its average at the end of the week*/
void calories(){
    int day = 1;
    int total_intake = 0;
    int intake_per_day[7];
    int avg;
    int i = 1;
    struct calorie intake;
    FILE *fptr3;
    if((fptr3 = fopen("Clients.txt","a"))==NULL){
        printf("File was not opened\n");
    }
    for(day = 1; day < 7; day++){
        system("cls");
        printf("Please enter carbohydrate intake:");
        scanf(" %d",&intake.carbs);

        printf("Please enter protein intake:");
        scanf(" %d",&intake.protein);

        printf("Please enter fat intake:");
        scanf(" %d",&intake.fat);

        intake_per_day[i] = total(intake.carbs,intake.protein,intake.fat);
        fprintf(fptr3,"Day    Carbohydrates    Proteins    Fats    Total\n");
        fprintf(fptr3,"%d     %d               %d          %d       %d\n",day,intake.carbs,intake.protein,intake.fat,total_intake);
        i++;
    }
    for(i = 1;i < 7;i++){
        total_intake = total_intake + intake_per_day[i];
    }
    avg = total_intake / 7;
    fprintf(fptr3,"average intake for the week is: %d\n",avg);
    fclose(fptr3);
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Using `char username[10]; ... scanf("%s", user.username);` is asking for trouble.  `scanf("%9s", user.username);` is better.  Dropping `scanf()` everywhere and using `fgets()` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in

```
while((choice != 'Y') || (choice != 'y') || (choice !='N') || (choice != 'n')){
```

is flawed.

It will evaluate to true no matter what the input is. At least three of those conditionals will be true for any input.

If you want to force the user to enter `Y`, `y`, `N`, or `n`, you need to use
 use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
while((choice != 'Y') && (choice != 'y') && (choice !='N') && (choice != 'n')){
```

Also, `choice` is not initialized before its first use. My suggestion:

Create functions `get_choice` and `is_valid_choice`.
Call `get_choice` from from `main`. You can call `is_valid_choice` from either `main` or `get_choice`.

```
bool is_valid_choice(char choice)
{
   return (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y' || choice == 'N' || choice == 'n');
}

char get_choice()
{
   char choice;
   while ( scanf(" %c", &choice) > 0 && !is_valid_choice(choice));
   return choice;
}
```

and in `main`.

```
char choice = get_choice();

// Use choice as you see fit.
```

Comment: Also `char choice` not given a value before this test.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition will always evaluate to true because you use the `||` operator where you mean to use `&&`.  Every possible value of `choice` is unequal to either `'y'` or `'Y'`.